# SQL Server 2012 Permissions

Tags: sql-server, permissions

I need to give permission to one of our contractor to create a database and user on the SQL Server. What minimum permission should I grant and how?

Comment: If the need is to create 1 database and 1 user, I wouldn't have the contractor do it, I'd do it myself.

Answer (score 0):

To find the permissions required to execute some command you should simply open the corresponding BOL article.

You want to create database -- just open [CREATE DATABASE (SQL Server Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql) article.

> Requires `CREATE DATABASE`, `CREATE ANY DATABASE`, or `ALTER ANY
>   DATABASE` permission.

Then you want to create login. Open [CREATE LOGIN (Transact-SQL)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751(v=sql.110).aspx) article and go to PERMISSIONS:

> In SQL Server and SQL Server PDW, requires `ALTER ANY LOGIN`
>   permission on the server or membership in the `securityadmin` fixed
>   server role.